# Vue 3 CLI - How to add babel polyfill for Object.entries

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs, polyfills

I have a dependency (vue2-google-maps) which is causing issues with my Vue app in older browsers, throwing an error with `Object.entries`.

Reading the [Vue CLI Docs on polyfills](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#polyfills), I see it mention trying to load the polyfill in `babel.config.js`.

My `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ['@vue/app', {
      polyfills: [
        'es6.object'
      ]
    }]
  ]
}
```

Throws an error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: [BABEL] /PROJECT_DIR/src/main.js: Cannot read property 'android' of undefined (While processing: "/PROJECT_DIR/node_modules/@vue/babel-preset-app/index.js")
    at targetEnvironments.filter.environment (/PROJECT_DIR/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js:75:16)
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at isPluginRequired (/PROJECT_DIR/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js:74:56)
    at includes.filter.item (/PROJECT_DIR/node_modules/@vue/babel-preset-app/index.js:23:12)
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at getPolyfills (/PROJECT_DIR/node_modules/@vue/babel-preset-app/index.js:22:19)
    at module.exports (/PROJECT_DIR/node_modules/@vue/babel-preset-app/index.js:94:17)
    at loadDescriptor (/PROJECT_DIR/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:163:14)
    at cachedFunction (/PROJECT_DIR/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/caching.js:42:19)
    at loadPresetDescriptor (/PROJECT_DIR/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:233:63)
    at config.presets.map.descriptor (/PROJECT_DIR/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:68:19)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at recurseDescriptors (/PROJECT_DIR/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:66:38)
    at loadFullConfig (/PROJECT_DIR/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:106:6)
    at process.nextTick (/PROJECT_DIR/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:28:33)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:112:11)

 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.201:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

What am I doing wrong? I created the project with `Vue CLI 3.0.3`

Comment: Is it possible that your `browserlistrc` is not targeting those older browsers (which causes the polyfill to be stripped)?

Comment: While not an ideal solution, I simply put the raw code of the polyfill into my vue app's `main.js` file which works, but feels very hacky.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `es6.object` to `es7.object.entries` to make `Object.entries` work on older browsers.

So your `/babel.config.js` should look like the following:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      "@vue/app",
      {
        polyfills: ["es7.object.entries"]
      }
    ]
  ]
};
```

I have found the polyfills name here: [built-in-features.js#L153](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/880fc1f54e6d1cf4cb18ba82182d744dd76130fc/packages/babel-preset-env/data/built-in-features.js#L153)